# Android Studio: Subversion files are marked as unversioned

Tags: svn, android-studio

I have added my Android Studio project to Subversion. When I go to changes, all of my files are listed under "Unversioned Files". I have tried opening from Subversion by selecting "Check  out from Version Control", but even after doing this I ended up with all files marked as Unversioned.

If I try to add those files, I get the following error:
Error:Cannot find CVSROOT for file ...

How do I get Android Studio to properly work with SVN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, this is really silly, but took me forever to find out. By default, Android Studio seems to pick CVS as the version control for the project, even though I was checking the project out from Subversion! Bug, AFAIK.

Here is the fix:

1. File | Settings
2. Under project settings on the left, select Version Control
3. On the right, select Subversion from the dropdown next to the  directory (VCS column)

Problem solved!

[image: Screenshot of the settings page]

Comment: I had a similar problem. I just started using Bitbucket from the command line (not through an Android Studio GUI) and all my files' names turned a distracting burnt red color. I switched it from "Git" to "none" on this same screen, and it fixed my problem!