# Connecting Android Studio Project to SVN Repository

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I want to version control an Android Studio Project with Subversion. I have created a test android project in my dev machine and I have created a remote svn repository.

Then, after configuring subversion settings as instructed in [Connect Android Studio with SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679332/connect-android-studio-with-svn), I have selected ***VCS->Import into Version Control->Import into Subversion*** in order to import the project into the svn repository.

The problem is that, even if the files are imported into the repository, the project is not connected with it. In fact all of the project files are  listed as "Unversioned Files". When I make some changes to my code and try to commit it, it says "No changes detected" as reported in: [No changes to commit Android studio SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211273/no-changes-to-commit-android-studio-svn).

The same problem is faced in [Android Studio: Subversion files are marked as unversioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215368/android-studio-subversion-files-are-marked-as-unversioned) but the solution proposed is not working for me.

The only (stupid) "solution" seems to be the one proposed in this article [Android Studio and Subversion](http://www.monblocnotes.com/node/2052), where I have to import my project into subversion. Then delete all my local files and finally create a new Android Project with the ***Check out from Version Control*** option!!!

Is there a solution to import an android Studio Project into and svn repository and enforce that the project remains connected to the repo?

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: After exporting your project to svn. You have to check out the same project from SVN otherwise not able to commit any changes.

Comment: This has been bothering me too for quite some time, and first importing the project into SVN, deleting all local files and then checking it out again is indeed the only working "solution" that I have been able to find. I also started a question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369817/android-studio-create-new-project-in-empty-svn-repo but to no avail