# Android Studio - create new project in empty SVN repo

Tags: android, svn

In Eclipse, using the Subclipse plugin, I could create an empty SVN repo and then use the "Checkout as a project using the new project wizard" option to create a new Android project and immediately commit it to the empty SVN repo. In Android Studio I haven't found a way to do that without first creating the project, then importing it into version control and then checking it out again. I must be doing something wrong, help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can get answer here [Using SVN in Android Studio](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/svn/androidstudio.html)

1. If you create a new project that is not in your SVN repo, you need to import the project first (select "VCS" => "Import into version control" => "Import into subversion")
2. Add your repo address to it, for example, for the lab1 submission, the repo should be “https://svn.cs.dartmouth.edu/classes/cs65-W15/Your_Name/Lab1_submission/”(You don’t have to create the Lab1_submission on svn in advance, it will create it for you if it doesn’t exist).
3. Then choose your project folder, and click “import”.
4. Type your commit message, and click “OK”.
5. You may need to enter your SVN credentials.

> Please follow rest of the steps from link [Using SVN in Android
>   Studio](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/svn/androidstudio.html)

You can also follow [Android Studio and Subversion](http://www.monblocnotes.com/node/2052)

Comment: I knew about that, but problem is that when I do so the project IS committed into the repo, but then if I make changes and go to "VCS --> Commit Changes..." it says "No changes detected" even though I did modify source files. If I remove my local working copy and check it out again it does work, but I'm sure that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: anyone? I just want to initialize a new Android Studio project in an empty SVN repo and be able to commit changes without having to go through so much trouble. Thanks.