# Android Studio svn - unable to commit

Tags: svn, android-studio

I am an old user of subclipse and the version control in Android Studio is very different - causing me some problems...
I added project to SVN some days ago and today I reached certain milestone and decided to commit - much to my surprise, I couldn't - the files weren't even under version control. A quick search around Stack overflow and I've found the first hint:
[files in android studio unversioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215368/android-studio-subversion-files-are-marked-as-unversioned)
I followed the hints from here and now have all my files highlighter red (should mean they are out of sync to my understanding - which is right, because most of this files weren't even in the initial commit, others have changed dramatically)

The options I've tried:

- **Update Directory** with infinity depth : "No versioned directories to update was found"
- **Integrate Directory** with infinity depth and working copy : "No versioned directories to update was found" or "is not a working copy"
- **Add to VCS** : got massive list of files, each of them "is not a working copy" **a more notable one is svn: E155007: 'F:\dev\android\android-studio' is not a working copy** - the root directory of the project directory (something got messed up with paths perhaps?
- **Commit** : "No changes detected" - quite expectedly as nothing is versioned.
- **update project** "no versioned directories to update was found"
- **Import into Subversion** infinity depth, just like a fresh import into SVN: " Cannot import to svn: svn: E160020: File '.gitignore' already exists - shortly speaking I can't import into, because it's already there.

*I don't want to resort to external svn tool like tortoiseSVN as the built in functionality is a must have for me, so only way of making the svn work in Android Studio is a solution here. I never had this kind of problem with subclipse, so my suspicion is something is missing that subclipse did automatically for me that I need to be aware of here*